# How can I use a checkbox to show or hide a graph that is inputed from a csv file?

Tags: javascript, html, csv, dygraphs

So basically I have been working with some code to try and use a checkbox to hide/show a graph, the big issue is that the graph is made using dygraph and the graphs are made from a csv file's data therefore there is no specific line of code that the graph corresponds with. I am basically stuck because I really don't know how to get around this problem. I can go in to the website once the data is inputed and show/hide the graph that way however different file will have different amounts of data so I can't just do that every time.

Answer (score 0):

When you create the graph, you specify a `div` that the graph should be drawn in. Can't you simply show/hide that `div`?